# Include playhead position in premiere pro history

Tags: premiere

Here we have a cut and we see the playhead a bit to the left (the green line).

[image: Clip with cut and playhead to the left]

Pressing Q will trim the clip from the start to the playhead, resulting in

[image: Clip trimmed from start]

Now when I ctrl-Z (undo), I get

[image: after undoing, the playhead position is lost]

The playhead position is now in the start instead of where I had it before.

Can I include playhead position into the undo mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can.  Try using the Lift and Extract functions instead of cutting using the playhead position.

Set the In and Out points using <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>O</kbd>

"Lift" the section you want to remove using <kbd>;</kbd> if you want to "lift" it (copy it, leaving a gap in the timeline)

Or use <kbd>'</kbd> if want to "extract" (copy it and ripple the rest of the timeline.

You playhead position will be unaffected.

More here:
https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/lift-extract-premiere-pro/